# Computing the Darboux integral of $x$ on $[0,1]$ by definition.

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I was wondering whether one can prove brute force without the notion of the Riemann sums the fact that

$$ \underline{\int}_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2} $$

I am trying to do this without any theorems about integrals just by definition, but I am struggling with this for some reason. A brief search has also yielded no proof for this fact. Has anyone encountered such a proof for this or perhaps provide me with some?

Comment: Take the partition $P_n$ formed by the points ${k \over n}$, $k=0,...,n$. Then compute $L(f,P_n), U(f,P_n)$. It is straightforward.

Comment: That is using the fact that as long as the partition's mesh tends to $0$, somehow intertwining the Riemann integral with the notion of Darboux integral. I'm looking for a solution strictly with Upper Darboux sum, and without using the relation between Darboux integral and Riemann integral.

Comment: I am just using the Darboux integral which is equivalent. You have $L(f,P_n) \le \int f \le U(f,P_n)$ and since both upper and lower values converge to ${1 \over 2}$ you are finished. I don't understand what the last sentence in your comment means.

Comment: You are right, I confused myself. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this fine? Let $\mathcal{P}_n=\{0,1/n,2/n,...,(n-1)/n,1\}$ be a partition with $n$ subintervals. Then if $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ then we have 
$$L(\mathcal{P}_n,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\min_{x\in[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}f(x)\Delta x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}.$$
Now taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ gives the desired result.

Comment: This computation is not exactly what I wanted, but combined with copper.hat's comment this does solve it.

Comment: Sounds good. Indeed from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral, a function is Darboux integrable iff it is Riemann integrable.